# How to install Emgu.cv xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My question is simple i want to install emgu.cv in xamarin forms via nuget package but it return me error.

```
Error   NU1202  Package ZedGraph 5.1.7 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package ZedGraph 5.1.7 supports: net35-client (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Client)  App19.iOS   

Error   NU1202  Package ZedGraph 5.1.7 is not compatible with monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0). Package ZedGraph 5.1.7 supports: net35-client (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Client)   App19.Android   C:\Users\bonka\source\repos\App19\App19\App19.Android\App19.Android.csproj  1
```

Comment: The errors tell you what the problem is... apparently the package is not compatible with either iOS and Android versions you have in your project.

Comment: Yes this is the reason

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18145): The Emgu CV Nuget package targets .Net framework instead of .NET standard framework, it is for Windows desktop application only. Xamarin forms only support iOS, Android, UWP and Mac, it is not compatible with the Emgu CV nuget pacakge.